# Outlook preview feature incorrectly displays symbols by HTML codes

Tags: html, encoding, outlook

Let's assume the following HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>&boxvr; test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser shows the following result:

```
├ test
```

But the Outlook preview attachment feature (right-click attachment -> Preview) shows the raw content of the <p> tag:

```
&boxvr; test
```

Trying using the "├" symbol inside HTML leads to the following result of using the Preview feature:

```
в”њ test
```

Is there any way to put the"├" symbol in the HTML file, so the Outlook attachment preview displays it correctly?
The outlook version is 1902.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help you with your problem:
try using

```
&#9500;
&#x251C;
```

please let me know if it works.

Comment: It works, thank you! Seems, I was not using HTML symbol code, but some kind of alias.